# Add / Remove icon base on the JavaScript result

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my view, based on the javascript result I'm getting from the Ajax call, I want to add and remove the icon class for a div area.

So far I did this,

```
<div class="form-group row"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskDetailsList.First().Service_Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 required" }) <div class="d-flex">
    <div> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskDetailsList.First().Service_Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = true } }) </div>
    <div class="align-self-center ms-auto" id="iconforPay">
      <span id="PaymentStatus"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

on the javascript,

```
if (direc == 0) {
  console.log("true");
  document.getElementById('PaymentStatus').innerHTML = "Payment Completed";
  $(".iconforPay").append('<i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill font-24 color-green-dark"></i>');
} else {
  console.log("false");
  document.getElementById('PaymentStatus').innerHTML = "Payment Pending";
  $(".iconforPay").append('<i class="bi bi-hourglass-top-fill font-24 color-red-dark"></i>');
}
```

What I wanted to do is, if the result is ==0 then I want to show `Payment Completed` text on the `span id="PaymentStatus"` and then need to show the `icon class`.

Else I want to show `span id="PaymentStatus"` as `Payment Pending` and add the related icon to there.

Here `Text` is changing, but the icon is not showing.

Also, Need to know, how to remove `icon class` in the start of the javascript and adding with the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you added CDN link for the bootstrap icon exactly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Remove icon class.

```
$(".bi-check-circle-fill").removeClass("color-red-dark")
```

if you remove a class and want to add new class, you can do this like this.

```
$(".bi-check-circle-fill").removeClass("color-red-dark").addClass("color-green-dark")
```

If you run this code when the page is loaded, you can add this code in `document.ready` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bi-check-circle-fill").removeClass("color-red-dark")
});
```